# obtener valor input para minDate

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Con la  función de abajo pasa unas fechas desde  y hasta, mediante un calendario.
Necesito que al pulsar en el input 'hasta' obtenga la fecha del input 'desde' para informar al minDate.
Como lo estoy haciendo:
minDate: $("#desde"+x).val().
.. no me funciona.
Muchas gracias

```
var x = 1;

            $(addButton).click(function(){ //Once add button is clicked
                if(x < maxField){ //Check maximum number of input fields
                    x++; z++;
                    //Increment field counter
                    var fieldContainer = $(fieldContainerHTML);

var fieldContainerHTML = '<div ><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="remove" ><img src="calendario/images/delete.png"  /><br /></a><div><br/>';

var fieldInput  = $('<input type="text" name="desde['+x+']" id="desde'+x+'" class="uno" size="9" placeholder="Desde"/> &nbsp;').calendario({time: false,    clearButton: true,  }); 
var fieldInput2  = $('<input type="text" name="hasta['+x+']" id="hasta'+x+'" size="9" class="dos" placeholder="Hasta"/>').calendario({time: false,  clearButton: true, minDate: $("#desde"+x).val() }); 
var fieldInputHTML  = ' &nbsp;<select name="alias['+x+']" id="alias'+x+'"  class="requerido" style="width: 90px;">  <option value="" selected="selected">Apartamento</option><?php echo $casas; ?>  &nbsp;  <input type="text" class="importe" name="precio['+x+']" id="precio'+x+'" size="7" placeholder="Precio día"/>  <input type="hidden"  name="seleccion['+x+']"  value="tarifa" />';   

var fieldContainer = $(fieldContainerHTML); //Construimos el objeto jquery y lo guardamos en una variable para hacer referencia después.
fieldContainer.prepend(fieldInput,fieldInput2,fieldInputHTML); // Añadimos el input al html contenedor
$(wrapper).append(fieldContainer); // Añadimos los nodos html al wrapper            
// Construimos el input y le asociamos el datepicker
                }
            });
```

Comment: El código no está ordenado, no está completo (por ejemplo no se incluye la declaración de addButton, maxField entre otros. Además mezcla comentarios en inglés y español. De todas formas te dejé una respuesta mostrando un ejemplo muy sencillo.

Answer (score 0):

El código de la pregunta tiene mucho "ruido". A continuación un ejemplo usando JavaScript puro:

Lo siguiente agrega la fecha del campo "Desde" como fecha mínima del campo "Hasta" al salir del primero.

```js
var desde = document.getElementById('desde');
desde.addEventListener('change', setMin);

function setMin() {
  var hasta = document.getElementById('hasta');
  hasta.min = desde.value;
}
```

```html
<div>Desde: <input type="date" id="desde"></div>
<div>Hasta: <input type="date" id="hasta"></div>
```